# how do i tell if a vector is parallel to another vector in $\Bbb R^6$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

[image]

So far in my book I haven't learned any of the parallel or perpendicular notation.. so there must be some way to tell this answer that the book hasn't told me.. I looked back and there was nothing describing how to do it. How?

Comment: Forget this is in $\mathbb R^6$ for the moment; how would you do this if you had vectors in $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: A vector $v$ is parallel to $u$ if $v = ku$ for some scalar $k$.

Comment: so b is the only parallel vector.. by inspection.. oh... and c

Comment: @user139388 Do you require the scalar $k$ to be nonzero?  Otherwise (c) is also acceptable.

Comment: @SpamIAm nope. The zero vector is parallel to everything. It's like the super agreeable guy in the room ;)

Comment: @user139388: But then being parallel is no longer symmetric: While for any vector $v$, we have $0=0v$, there is no nonzero vector $v$ such that $v=k 0$ for any $k$.

Comment: Perhaps we should not keep inviting that super-agreeable guy to our parties. I think that the parallel relation is best restricted to vectors in $\mathbb R^n - \{0\}$, then it does indeed become a symmetric relation, and in fact an equivalence relation.

Comment: I agree with @LeeMosher merely $k0=0$ so the only vector parallel to zero is itself, although rather than rescinding the invitation I'd give zero the place of honor and respect it deserves, singling it out for it's unique and ubiquitous role in algebra. Perhaps a throne for $0$ would do instead.

Comment: Being the king isn't all just glory; there are some activities the king can't participate in. "Being parallel to others" seems to be one.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already mentioned checking that one is a scalar multiple of another (and this is indeed the easiest way) but another possible method is to check if
$$\mathbf{u}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{v}=\Vert \mathbf{u}\Vert \Vert \mathbf{v} \Vert$$
If so, the vectors are parallel. If you're not working in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we can use $\langle \mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\rangle$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Answers is $(b)$ and $(c)$ since we have $\textbf u= -\frac 12\textbf v$, where $v=(4,-2,0,-6,-10,-2)$, and $\textbf 0=0 \textbf u$.

It is worth it to mention that two vectors $\textbf u, \textbf v\in\mathbb R^3$  are parallel if the vector product $\textbf u \times \textbf v$ is equal to null vector $\textbf 0$.

Comment: Or, in general, two vectors $w,v\in\Bbb R^n$ are parallel if and only if $$\operatorname{rk}(w;v)<2$$ i.e. if and only if $w_iv_j-v_iv_j=0$ for all $i,j$.

Comment: Another criterion for parallelism that works in every dimension is checking this identity of dot products: $$\left\langle u; v\right\rangle^2=\left\langle u; u\right \rangle \left\langle v;v\right\rangle$$